# iframe javascript after onload

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

When iframe is loading I use a css class 'active' when is stop loading I switch to 'inactive' class.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function frameload(){
    document.getElementById("loadnav").className = "active";
}
document.getElementById("loadnav").className = "inactive";
</script>
<iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" onload="frameload()"></iframe>
```

The problem is that after loading does not return to 'inactive'.

Comment: I think you have to remove the initial class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things

1. You don't have an `id` on your iframe so `document.getElementById` won't do anything
2. There needs to be some listener for `DOMContentLoaded` because `document.getElementById("loadnav").className = "inactive";` is trying to run before the `iframe` is actually on the page

```css
iframe {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
iframe.inactive {
border: 2px solid red;
}
iframe.active {
border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script>
function frameload(){
    document.getElementById("loadnav").className = "active";
}
function init(){
  document.getElementById("loadnav").className = "inactive";
  document.getElementById("loadnav").addEventListener('load', frameload);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);

</script>

<iframe src="https://www.wikipedia.org/" id='loadnav'></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

are you tried to use jQuery. the  instruction document.getElementById("loadnav").className = "inactive"; is executed after the loading the iframe

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
 document.getElementById("loadnav").className = "inactive";
});
```